# html2canvas 1.0.0-alpha.12 getting snapshot without background styling

Tags: javascript, canvas, background, html2canvas

I have object(chair) in .png file and I am changing its color on browser from jquery by changing background color and it is working fine.

[image: This is output of after changing the color of chair]

My question is now I am trying to save this change colored chair image by using html2canvas js library, but it saves image without background effect of changing color.

[image: and this is output of saved image after changing color of chair]

My code of convert html to canvas image by using html2canvas library of version 1.0.0-alpha.12 is here :

```
html2canvas($("#chair")[0]).then(function(canvas) {
  $("#element-out").append(canvas);
});
```

Help me to save image with background effects of changing color of chair. Thankyou!

Comment: Without the code reproducing your issue there is very little anyone can do, also the way you describe this sounds like a bug in html2canvas, you should report it with them: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/new

Comment: ok I am reporting this issue to them, Thank you!

Comment: Ohh sorry, now i get it thanks!